# Can I fake being in the customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to get a list of all theme mods / options currently registered. The normal way you can do it is to be inside the customizer, then `$wp_customize->settings()`.

This will return a `k,v` pair of all the currenty registered theme mods that can, say, be saved.

If I inspect the global `wp_customize` outside the customizer itself, it's null, as expected.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fake being in the customizer, just grab the theme mods directly via `get_theme_mods`. Afterall they're just theme specific options.

Something like this would print out all the theme mods in a definition list:

```php
function tomjn_print_theme_mods() {
    $mods = get_theme_mods();
    if ( empty( $mods ) {
        return;
    }
    echo '<dl>';
    foreach ( $mods as $k => $v ) {
        echo '<dt>'.esc_html( $k ).'</dt>';
        echo '<dd>'.esc_html( $v ).'</dd>';
    }
    echo. '</dl>';
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mods

Comment: I thought so too, initially. But then you go ahead and inspect the `settings()` and you see way more things being there than in the `$theme_name$_theme_mods` option that `get_theme_mods` gives you. I have no idea how it works internally, I just know you must be inside the customizer to see these options.

Comment: Then some of them might be options or generated, but I know for certain that what you're. trying to do is rare and unusual, and that there's no way to "fake" the customizer. Perhaps if you asked about the original task you were trying to achieve/solve rather than how to implement this solution I'd be able to give a more useful answer?

Comment: I frankly forgot. I feel bad for even asking. Been working for 16 hours now. The customizer has another type of theme mod that you can't see unless you go inside of it. If you could help with an idea, I will reword my question to fit that.

Comment: hmmm do you have an example of that? It'd be good to try and reproduce it so I can figure out what it's doing